# How to schedule a task at go periodically?

Tags: go, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

Is there any native library or third party support like `ScheduledExecutorService` by java native library at go lang for production use case?

Please find the code snippet in java 1.8 :

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class TaskScheduler {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable runnable = ()-> {
                // task to run goes here
                System.out.println("Hello !!");
        };
        ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        service.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    }

}
```

It will print `Hello !!` in every one second.

Comment: `I found some implementation in go by using Timer, but not satisfied for the production use-case.` we need more explanation about this one why are you not satisfied

Comment: Need pool of routines for executing one task per routine and no memory leakage :) @xpare

Comment: I would say that needing a pool of routines sounds like something a go routine will fill. Ranging a timer and stopping it when you're done will not leak memory

Answer (score 37, accepted):

No need to use 3rd party library to achieve that. Simply take the advantage of goroutine and use available `time.Sleep()` API from `time` package, then the very same result can be achieved.

Example:

```golang
go func() {
    for true {
        fmt.Println("Hello !!")
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    }
}()
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/IMV_IAt-VQX

---

### Example using ticker #1

As per suggestion from Siddhanta. Here is one example to achieve the same result by using ticker (taken from [go documentation page of ticker](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#NewTicker), with some modifications following your requirement).

```golang
done := make(chan bool)
ticker := time.NewTicker(1 * time.Second)

go func() {
    for {
        select {
        case <-done:
            ticker.Stop()
            return
        case <-ticker.C:
            fmt.Println("Hello !!")
        }
    }
}()

// wait for 10 seconds
time.Sleep(10 *time.Second)
done <- true
```

The ticker time information (the time when the `Hello !!` executed) can be taken from `ticker.C` channel.

```golang
case t := <-ticker.C:
    fmt.Println(t)
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/TN2M-AMr39L

---

### Example using ticker #2

Another simplified example of ticker, taken from https://gobyexample.com/tickers

```golang
ticker := time.NewTicker(1 * time.Second)
go func() {
    for range ticker.C {
        fmt.Println("Hello !!")
    }
}()

// wait for 10 seconds
time.Sleep(10 *time.Second)
ticker.Stop()
```

Comment: Actually it would be best to use a [time.Ticker](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#NewTicker)

Comment: You don't need `for true {}`, just `for {}`.

Comment: What happens if you don't stop the ticker at all?